# Is it true that for any integral domain $D$ , $\text{Frac}(D)[x] \cong \text{Frac}(D[x])$?

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

Is it true that for any integral domain $D$ , $\text{Frac}(D)[x] \cong \text{Frac}(D[x])$ ? , where $\text{Frac}$ denotes the fraction field of the integral domain . I am at a complete loss, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, is $x$ invertible in both?

Comment: @ZhenLin: yeah , I think though $x$ is invertible in the right hand field , it is not invertible in the left hand polynomial ring , so they are not isomorphic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Is $Frac(D)[x]$ always a field? Is $Frac(D[x])$ always a field? Note the first one has the form $R[x]$ and the second one $Frac[S]$, with $R$ and $S$ rings.